# Scrape webpage containing ::before

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My question is when using bs4 to scrape the HTML can't scrape contains like `::before`.

I want to know the company contributes to which SDGs in a page.
https://www.unglobalcompact.org/participation/report/cop/create-and-submit/active/395091
but the checkmark is invisible in a source code.

What should I do or what can I use to scrape it from the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `::before::` part here at all. Selected and not selected elements have different classes - selected has `selected_question`, not selected `advanced_question`.

You can parse it using something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://www.unglobalcompact.org/participation/report/cop/create-and-submit/active/395091"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

questions = soup.select("ul.questionnaire > li.question_group")
for question in questions:
    question_text = question.get_text(strip=True)
    print(question_text)

    answers = question.find_next_siblings("li")
    for answer in answers:
        answer_text = answer.get_text(strip=True)
        is_selected = "selected_question" in answer.get("class", [])

        print(answer_text, is_selected)
    print("-----")
```

Would print:

```
Which of the following Sustainable Development Goals (SDGs) do the activities described in your COP address? [Select all that apply]
SDG 1: End poverty in all its forms everywhere False
SDG 2: End hunger, achieve food security and improved nutrition and promote sustainable agriculture False
SDG 3: Ensure healthy lives and promote well-being for all at all ages True
SDG 4: Ensure inclusive and equitable quality education and promote lifelong learning opportunities for all False
...
```

Note the `True` printed for the answers which were selected.

I've also noticed that this code does not properly work if `html.parser` is chosen as a parser.